# ¿Cómo rellenar los guiones en el ahorcado?

Tags: javascript

Tengo un problema a la hora de rellenar los espacios con guiones en el juego del ahorcado y no sé cómo podría solucionarlo. A mi modo de verlo tienen toda la lógica del mundo lo que estoy haciendo pero no sé por qué no rellena la letra que es con la posición en la palabra. He preferido hacer la pregunta más pequeña para llegar antes a la solución así que adjunto el código con comentarios para que nadie se pierda.

```html
<html>

<body>
  <script>
    "use strict";

    //Declaro una palabra para hacerla luego guiones, como en un ahorcado
    var palabra = "pulga";

    //Ahora separo esa palabra en comas y la despiezo por letras
    var separo = palabra.split("");

    //Con esto, mi intención es poner la letra que va en la posición correspondiente
    //a la palabra. Si no, se pondrá un guión.
    for (var i = 0; i < palabra.length; i++) {
      if (separo[i] == letraInicial) //<-- Esto no me está funcionando
      {
        separo[i] = letraInicial;
      } else {
        separo[i] = " _ ";
      }

    }

    //Declaro un String
    var letra = "p";

    //Con esta función saco la primera letra para que sea solo un carácter.
    function asd(letra) {
      var soloIinicial = letra.charAt(0);

      return soloIinicial;
    }

    //Guardo esa letra en una variable.
    var letraInicial = asd(letra);
  </script>
  <h1>
    <script>
      document.write(separo + "</br>");
    </script>
  </h1>
</body>
Etiquetas
```

Comment: Crea un elemento `span` para cada letra y asigna ID de acuerdo a posición, al inicio, todos van a tener `_`. Después puedes obtenerlo con `document.getElementByID()` para actualizar. Definitivamente, no debes usar `document.write()`.

Comment: `letraInicial` no existe cuando haces el reemplazo, moviendo esa parte al principio ahí funciona

Answer (score 0):

Cree una solución que quizá podría servirte. Te recomiendo no colocar la etiqueta script directamente para colocar el elemento html que quieres mostrar. En vez de eso, crea una referencia usando document.getElementById para poder manipular al DOM desde un solo script separado.

Puede que no te esté funcionando dado que accedes a letrainicial antes de inicializarla. Podrías intentar hacer algo parecído a esto.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Ahorcado</title>

  <style>
    .mt20 {
      margin-top: 20;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" id="palabra" placeholder="Escribe la palabra a ocultar">
  <button onclick="separarPalabra()">Subir palabra</button>
  <span id="palabra_separada" class="mt20"></span>

  <script>
      // Obtenemos el input 
      const inputPalabra = document.getElementById('palabra')
      const palabraSeparadaLabel = document.getElementById('palabra_separada')

      function separarPalabra() {
        const palabrasSeparadas = inputPalabra.value.split("")

        let palabraAConstruir = palabrasSeparadas[0];
        let lineas = "";
        for (let index = 0; index < palabrasSeparadas.length; index++) {
          if(index !== 0) {
             lineas = lineas + ",___"
          }
        }
        palabraAConstruir = palabraAConstruir + lineas

        palabraSeparadaLabel.innerText = palabraAConstruir
      }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Versión con INPUTS**

Con esta versión deberías poder capturar los valores de los elementos input que estas creando, ya sea asignandoles un id cada vez que los creas o iterando el ancestro para capturar los values de cada uno de sus hijos.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Ahorcado</title>

  <style>
    .mt20 {
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
    .mr10 {
      margin-right: 10px;
    }
    .short_input {
      width: 25px;
    }
    .bottom_line {
      border: none;
      border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }

  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" id="palabra" placeholder="Escribe la palabra a ocultar">
  <button onclick="separarPalabra()">Subir palabra</button>
  
  <div id="input_group" class="mt20">
   
  </div>

  <script>
      // Obtenemos el input 
      const inputPalabra = document.getElementById('palabra')
      const inputGroup = document.getElementById('input_group') 
      function separarPalabra() {
        const palabrasSeparadas = inputPalabra.value.split("")

        let letraInicial = palabrasSeparadas[0];
        let lineas = "";
        for (let index = 0; index < palabrasSeparadas.length; index++) {
          const lineInput = document.createElement('input')
          lineInput.classList += 'short_input bottom_line mr10'    
          lineInput.setAttribute('maxlength', 1)
          if(index === 0) {
             lineInput.value = letraInicial
             lineInput.readOnly = true
             inputGroup.append(lineInput)
          } else {
             inputGroup.append(lineInput)
          }
        }
      }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muy interesante esta versión que has proporcionado pero a la hora de insertar valores como para intentar adivinar la palabra, ¿cómo sería?

Comment: Hola vicaro, puedes modificar la solución colocando unos inputs en vez de los span. Luego si quieres les asignas un id a cada uno y capturas su valor por medio de javascript. De tal manera que puedas comparar si la entrada es igual a la palabra que tu selecciones. Voy a actualizar la solución para que más o menos veas como sería.